# Opencart 2 persistent cart

Tags: cookies, opencart, session-cookies, shopping-cart, opencart2.x

Is there any way that I can make a persistent cookie for Opencart 2 shopping cart? I want the user to have the products saved in cart after the browser closes and to stay longer in cart if the browser is not closed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: the items added to the cart and wishlist are saved in the database and retrieved from there whenever a user requests it. No matter how many times the browser closes or not is irrelevant. Why would you want to add cookies to this process?

Comment: Maybe for authenticated users. I need something for every user. At this moment when I close the browser the items for the cart are removed.

Comment: why not try and save it in a session or local.storage instead?